In which episode does Lesbian Robin first appear
I've seen How I Met Your Mother many times, but I'm not sure if there is any episode which introduces Lesbian Robin.

Lesbian Robin is introduced in Double Date in one of Ted's flashbacks along with Moustache Marshall.
These two are the only Doppelgangers who don't get a full episode.
Also see this
